# optimise Tensorflow learning rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, rate

How could I find the best learning rate and decay rate dynamically?

The function like tf.train.exponential_decay cannot be changed dynamically based on the different cases since the starting rate and decay rate are pre-defined.

Comment: are you able to pause training at each epoch and change the learning rate?

Comment: Yes, I can. But the point is how could I decide this rate to be the best value at certain point.

Comment: @YingchaoXiong this is an unsolved problem in AI research

Comment: ... ... Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: that's tricky. In general, you want to decrease the learning rate over time, but like @YaroslavBulatov said, it's unknown.

Answer (score 3):

This is an open research problem, but on large batches backtracking line-search can be useful.

Note that your loss function is approximately linear for small enough neighborhood, so if you take small enough steps, you can predict what your loss decrease would be.

So the idea is that you look at predicted decrease in loss against actual decrease. If it's too close, you were too conservative and you increase your step size. If it's too far, do the opposite.

There's no built-in primitive to do this in TensorFlow, but you can implement it using lower level ops. Here's an end-to-end example on MNIST autoencoder: https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/tree/master/line_search_example

The learning rate quickly goes up to 0.05, and then after you've converged it can't make progress, so it drops to zero.

[image]